# Viewing a git log

Tags: git

I can run `git log --pretty='format:%ci::%an <%ae>::%s::%H!!!' --since=1/1/1900` on a cloned repository. Is it possible to get the same output without having to clone the repository first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible. You can do a git ls-remote to list the files. But there is no equivalent for seeing the logs.

If the git project has a web interface, you might probably be able to browse it through the web interface.

A similar thread is [here](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/View-remote-logs-td1331881.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to perform that operation on any git repo.
No, you don't have to clone the repo first, but you have to have one.
Either by init or forking.

I think your asking if you can view logs remotely.
However, this currently isn't supported.
[Git remote log and changes request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288598/git-remote-log-and-changes-request)